# Bq Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition: desktop mode question

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, bq

I'm so interested in buying the Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition! Ubuntu on desktop rules, I'm using it since 2008 :-) I'm actually a light computer user and I do 99% of my daily tasks in the cloud (using tools like OneDrive.com, Word Online via OneDrive, Transifex.com, etc.) So I'm looking to make this tablet both my tablet and laptop.

But I need to know one thing: as I also want to make this my laptop, will the desktop mode on screen (desktop mode on the tablet itself, as demoed at MWC 2016 using bluetooth kb/mouse) be available when the tablet goes on sale? 'Cause I really want desktop mode when needed on the tablet itself rather than hooking it up to a big screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You will be able to switch to windowed mode, even when not connected to an external display (a switch will be available in the quick access top-menu). And yes, it has been confirmed that this will be available on the Aquaris M10 when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that on the M10 (I'm writing using it) there's a switch to enable Desktop mode even without any connected keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, switching to desktop mode is possible and easy. However, installing Ubuntu Desktop Applications is not not easy. Gimp, Firefox and Libre Office are per-installed. Installing additional applications is more complicated. Firstly you need the application for the ARM CPU platform. Regular applications for Intel or AMD CPUs will not run on the tablet. Therefore I am not aware of any possibility to install Google Chrome - which would allow to watch Netflix. Also installing Thunderbird (standard in Ubuntu for Desktop) is not that easy and on a fingertip.

Don't get me wrong, I love my Ubuntu Touch on the Aquaris M10 - but I am limited in the things I am doing. I am eager to see more functions becoming available, even so it will take some time. What I am missing most these days is not being able to stream Netflix or Amazon Prime.

Comment: Chromium is available for ARM and so is Thunderbird. OTA-11 (the next update) will allow you to install those applications.